# Javascript OOP question - Changing element properties

Tags: javascript, oop, properties

I am trying to understand why neither of the commented out scripts work.  When I step through the code in the console they are both returning the correct variable values but neither of the commented out code changes the image size.  I would think that either one of commented set of scripts would be the correct as opposed to the way that works.  If someone could please help me with what I am not understanding it would be greatly appreciated.  thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  </head>
  <body>
         <img onmouseover = "increaseSize(this)" id="img2" width="400px" height="400px" src="20191128chichenitza.jpg" title="Chichenitza">

    <script>
    
        function increaseSize(y) {
        var currWidth = y.clientWidth*1.50;
        var currHeight = y.clientHeight*1.50;
        y.width = currWidth;
        y.height = currHeight;

        /*document.getElementById("img2").style.width = currWidth;
          document.getElementById("img2").style.height = currHeight;
          or
        y.style.width = currWidth;
        y.style.height = currHeight;
        */
        }
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `.style.width` must be set in the same way as you would in CSS. Therefore, `y.style.width = currWidth + "px"`;

Comment: Thanks that was it.   Please correct me if this thought is wrong but the y.width = currWidth; works because I am changing a property value of the img tag that doesnt require the px specification.  Again thanks

Comment: @JonnMc -- In the case of `y.width` you are assigning a width value to the [`.width` property of `HtmlImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/width) that expects a number. In the case of `.style.width`, you are changing the `.width` property of the 'style' object (the type of which I am not sure) which expects a string.